# The intersection of history, mathematics, and geography

Tags: mathematicians

I was looking for some material on the history of fractional calculus and googled Pincherle Amaldi to find a source. Up popped a map of the environs of the University of Rome and there was the intersection of Via Amaldi and Via Pincherle. One day, should I be in the area, I'll have to visit a coffee shop near the intersection and pay homage to the two.

Where can similar intersections be found?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is about the history of science and mathematics. Instead, it seems to be a question about (coincidences in) city planning and/or street naming.

Comment: In Germany, when a whole new area is built quickly and out of nothing, then usually they pick a theme for the street names, like trees or musicians or city names e.g., and I've also seen scientists names. I might remember the Marie-Curie-Street meeting the Max-Planck-Street as well as the Albert-Einstein-Street in the town next to my home town, so I think it's likely that there are a lot of (non-)coincidences of this kind.

Comment: The streets that you mentioned are just next to the mathematics faculty of Rome University, so there is nothing coincidental about them.

Comment: What seems unusual is that the two mathematicians I mentioned jointly published at least one paper.